# Throttle download traffic in apache for all users

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

Lets say I subdomain called largefiles.domain.com This is on a dedicated server and I can change any configuration. Server runs Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

How do i restrict all file downloads to just 10Kbps for every file downloaded from the webserver? What is the easiest solution to implement this for the entire subdomain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for [mod_bw](http://ivn.cl/#bandwidth):

Example: Limit every user to a max of 10Kb/s on a vhost :

```
<Virtualhost *>
  BandwidthModule On
  ForceBandWidthModule On
  Bandwidth all 10240
  MinBandwidth all -1
  Servername www.example.com
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: The documentation says:
ForceBandWidthModule [On|Off] 
    By default, the mod wont catch every request.
    If you enable it, every request will be processed by the mod.

Comment: Does not work with AJP.

Answer (score 0):

mod_cband should fix this for you.

See this nice tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling